# Retrieve Data via SOAP and send them to MYSQL-Database

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, soap, wsdl

I would like to recieve some data via SOAP from our PBX System and send them to our Mysql Database. Acutally with my script I am able to display the relevant data in a browser. However I need to write some data to my Mysql Database. For Example: The Phonenumber is: "e164" and I need to write it in my Mysql Database, when the Personal ID is the same as in the PBX. Is it possible to save the Phonenumber in an array and then deliver it back to Mysql Database? What are my options? I did also write an automatic CSV import for another task, which I could use. Therefore it would also be able to export the data by PHP-Skript to an CSV and then upload it. But I prefer a direct synchronisation. 
Thanks in Advance. If you need additional Informations, let me know.

The wsdl can be found here:
http://www.innovaphone.com/wsdl/pbx900.wsdl

My PHP-Script looks like this at the moment:

```
<?php

// get the wrapper class
require_once('wrapperclass.php');

//  Display Error
ini_set("display_errors",1);

// dummy classes to map SOAP results to (really would love to use namespaces here...)
// you can add methods and variables to these classes as needed
class innoUserInfo { };
class innoCallInfo { };
class innoAnyInfo { };
class innoGroup { };
class innoNo { };
class innoInfo { };

// Connectiondetails for Mysql Database
define('DB_SERVER', 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXX');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'Phonedatabase');

// Phonedatabase Connection Details. Soap User for connect
$server = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
$user = "XXX";
// User for login
$httpu = "XXX";
// Password
$httpp = "XXX";

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$inno = new innoPBX($server, $httpu, $httpp, $user,
        array('classmap' => array("UserInfo" => "innoUserInfo", 
                "CallInfo" => "innoCallInfo",
                "AnyInfo" => "innoAnyInfo",
                "Group" => "innoGroup",
                "No" => "innoNo",
                "Info" => "innoInfo",
                )));
if ($inno->key() == 0) die("failed to login to PBX");

// get version info
$v = $inno->Version();

function showInfos(&$poll, $head, $cn = "", $user = "", $call = "") {
    print $head . "\n";
    if ($cn !== null) {
    print count($poll->user) . " UserInfos\n";
    foreach($poll->user as $ui) {
        if (($cn === "") || ($cn == $ui->cn)) {
        print "     {$ui->cn} ({$ui->h323} #{$ui->e164}) state {$ui->state}\n";
        }
    }
    }
    if ($call !== null) {
    print count($poll->call) . " CallInfos\n";
    foreach($poll->call as $ci) {
        if ((($user === "") || ($user == $ci->user)) &&
        (($call === "") || ($call == $ci->call))) {
            print "    {$ci->user}/{$ci->call} {$ci->No[1]->h323} #{$ci->No[1]->e164} (remote {$ci->No[0]->h323} #{$ci->No[0]->e164}) msg {$ci->msg}\n";
        }
    }
    }
}

print "Retrieving User list for "; foreach ($v as $name => $value) print "\n  $name=$value "; print "...\n\n";
$seen = false;
$i = 1;
while (!$seen) {
    $p = $inno->Poll($inno->session());
    showInfos($p, "Poll() result #$i", "", null, null); $i++;
    if ($p->user[count($p->user)-1]->cn == "") {
    // we have seen all entries
    print " --- END OF LIST ---\n\n";
    $seen = true;
    break;
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

And also the Wrapperclass:

```
<?php

// innovaphone PBX SOAP API PHP wrapper class
//

class innoPBX extends SOAPClient {

    protected $___key;      // the session key
    protected $___session;  // the session id

    protected $___options = array(
                // default SOAPClient::__construct options used by the class
    "connection_timeout" => 10,
    "exceptions" => true,
    );

    const ___wsdl = 'http://www.innovaphone.com/wsdl/pbx900.wsdl';

    // class constructor
    public function __construct(
    $server,    // the PBX IP
    $httpu,     // the HTTP user id (e.g. "admin")
    $httpp,     // the HTTP password (e.g. "ip800")
    $user = null,       // the PBX user CN to work with 
    $options = null,
            // extra or overriding options for SOAPClient::__construct
    $wsdl = null    // the wsdl file location
    ) { 
    $wsdl = ($wsdl === null) ? self::___wsdl : $wsdl;
    $usedoptions = array(           // forced options
        'login' => $httpu,
        'password' => $httpp,
        'location' => "http://$server/PBX0/user.soap",
            );
    if (is_array($options)) $usedoptions += $options;   
                        // merge in user options
    $usedoptions += $this->___options;  // merged in class global options

    // construct parent class
    parent::__construct($wsdl, $usedoptions);

    // get the connection (using and activating v9 wsdl)
    $init = $this->Initialize($user, "PHP SOAP Wrapper", true, true, true, true, true);
    $this->___key = $init['key'];
    $this->___session = $init['return'];
    }

    public function key() { return $this->___key; }
    public function session() { return $this->___session; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your question is how to extract data from the SOAP object? This part of the sample code shows you how to do it:

```
foreach($poll->user as $ui) {
  if (($cn === "") || ($cn == $ui->cn)) {
        print "     {$ui->cn} ({$ui->h323} #{$ui->e164}) state {$ui->state}\n";
    }
}
```

For example, `$ui->cn` contains the name of the user. Store this value wherever you want or make a direct database input at this point.

See here for the complete documentation: [Reference10:Concept SOAP API](http://wiki.innovaphone.com/index.php?title=Reference10:Concept_SOAP_API)